# Can Ayurvedic treatment reduce symptoms and needed anti-inflammatory medication in ulcerative colitis patients by more than 75%

Tags: medical-science, nutrition, alternative-medicine

I found a study on [Research Gate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/51765538_Effects_of_Ayurvedic_treatment_on_forty-three_patients_of_ulcerative_colitis) titled

> Effects of Ayurvedic treatment on forty-three patients of ulcerative
> colitis

This paper was originally published in [An international quarterly journal of research in Ayurveda](https://www.ayujournal.org/article.asp?issn=0974-8520;year=2010;volume=31;issue=4;spage=478;epage=481;aulast=Patel;type=0)  and claims that Ayurvedic treatment has a highly significant effect on ulcerative colitis patients.

> In this study, it was observed that the symptoms and signs, daily dose
> of steroids and other anti-inflammatory drugs were reduced by more than 75% with a highly significant result. The hemoglobin level was also increased.

I am skeptical of these results for the reason that only 43 patients were included in the study and I’m not sure how significant of a result can be achieved with that number of people. I was also not able to find any kind of analysis of this paper nor the authors.

> A clinical study of 43 patients of ulcerative colitis has been
> conducted at the O.P.D.(outdoor patient department)and I.P.D.(indoor patient department)of the
> P D Patel Ayurveda Hospital, Nadiad.

> All the signs and symptoms were reduced by more than 80% and the
> reduction was statistically highly significant. RBCs in stool which is
> the main clinical sign of this disease was reduced by 93.02%.
> Hemoglobin increased by 16.76%. The dose of steroids was reduced by
> 87.32%. All the results were statistically highly significant.

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayurveda. Quote = he Indian Medical Association describes Ayurvedic practitioners who claim to practice medicine as quacks /quote. Highly unlikely that source would be striving for objectivity. Edit:  Describing it to be from ResearchGate is vague. The source if from "An International Quarterly Journal of Research in Ayurveda"

Comment: @pinegulf You are correct, I originally found it on research gate so I posted that link. I edited the question to include the original source.

Comment: Related and possibly not addressed - research has been published on large samples of people with this condition treated by placebo. About 26% see a benefit.  *Quantification of the placebo response in ulcerative colitis*  https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/9178676/

Answer (score 2):

The ayurvedic medication given to the study group consisted of multiple herbs and nature sourced ingredient. What the study does not mention, is that all it does is replace the dietary supplementation and needs recommended by western medicine with a different, unverified way of obtaining it.
For example, Kutaj has steroidal alkaloids that show potent anthelminthic, astringic, amoebicidal and diuretic activities and holds high significance in treating dysentery, diarrhoea and gastric ailments. Reference: https://pharmeasy.in/blog/ayurveda-benefits-side-effects-precautions-of-kutaja/ .

Udumbara kvatha basti, which is derived from cluster fig, can be high in calcium and fiber. As per western medicine, a balanced diet, dietary supplements rich in calcium and vitamins, are crucial in aiding the lack of nutrient intake of ulcerative colitis patients
Furthermore, the study group is put through an ayurvedic dietary regime, which is mostly just fruits, and minimal eating. This, along with the re-packaged replacement of verified dietary recommendations of modern medicine obviously can impact the symptoms and signs observed, one of which is bloody diarrhea.

Hence, all the study accomplishes is take the approach already recommended by modern medicine in terms of diet and supplementation, in an ineffective manner due to dosages that may not be enough or inadequate nutrient intake, and claim to be a valid replacement for modern medicine.

Comment: Excellent and informative first answer. Welcome to the site, enjoy Skeptics. (From review).